# JWT field 'kid' appearing in the header and the requirement is in the payload

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jwt

I am generating a JWT token.
But the requirement for the JWT token is, that a field called key id 'kid' should appear in the payload of the JWT, but it is appearing in the header. How can I achieve that?

my code:

```
    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(Objects.requireNonNull(environment.getProperty("signing_secret")).getBytes());

    Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("dd-ver", environment.getProperty("version"));
    headers.put("auth-version", environment.getProperty("auth-version"));

    String token = JWT.create()
        .withHeader(headers)
        .withAudience(environment.getProperty("audience"))
        .withIssuer(environment.getProperty("developer_id"))
        .withKeyId(environment.getProperty("key_id"))
        .withIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
        .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + THIRTY_MINUTES))
        .sign(algorithm);
```

Comment: The `kid` should appear in the header. Depending on the library you can try putting it into the payload "manually" using `withClaim(..., ...)`, but most likely not with `withKeyId` because that abides by the standard and puts it in the header.

Answer (score 0):

`withClaim` can add a custom property to JWT body. You can write your code like this.

```
String token = JWT.create()
            .withHeader(headers)
            .withAudience(environment.getProperty("audience"))
            .withIssuer(environment.getProperty("developer_id"))
            .withClaim("kid",environment.getProperty("key_id"))
            .withIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .withExpiresAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + THIRTY_MINUTES))
            .sign(algorithm);
```

We can find some illustrations from `com.auth0.jwt.JWTCreator`:

```
        /**
         * Add a custom Claim value.
         *
         * @param name  the Claim's name.
         * @param value the Claim's value.
         * @return this same Builder instance.
         * @throws IllegalArgumentException if the name is null.
         */
        public Builder withClaim(String name, String value) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            assertNonNull(name);
            addClaim(name, value);
            return this;
        }
```

```
        private void addClaim(String name, Object value) {
            if (value == null) {
                payloadClaims.remove(name);
                return;
            }
            // add custom property to the payload
            payloadClaims.put(name, value);
        }
```

Comment: thanks, that's what i did and it is where i need it now.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: thanks for your advice, I have added a few sections of the source code to support my answer.